# Why does my neural network approximate shifted functions so badly?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I wrote my own neural network in java, i started with a perceptron and expanded to a multilayer network with sigmoidal activation function, which is learning through SGD and backpropagation.

I am currently testing it, single layer and multi layer classification and regression work, linear and non-linear.

However, if I introduce a shift in the y-direction like

> f(x)= 2*x + 40

my network just approximates the inclination and not the + 20. If I monitor the weights it shows me that the bias(which is in charge of such shifts) is changing but very slowly and even if i let it learn for thousands of epochs it doesnt nearly reach the solution.

[Linear function where y=2*x + 40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXnHi.png)

A similar problem is with a square function where

> f(x)= x^2

, i can make my network as big and deep as I want, it doesnt converge perfectly, just a very rough approximation, like two linear graphs. I think this also due to  bias weights not converging properly or at least very slowly.

[neural network approximated square function, with 10 hidden neurons and one output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C3hm.png)

Anyways, my question now is, wether this is normal and i should just train longer or introduce a momentum or weight decay term, or if i implemented something wrong.

PS: I can provide code if that is necessary, I just wanted to keep this as short as possible. Didnt really work but I hope it's at least clear what i mean. Thank you all for your time in advance!

Comment: Did you norm training data?

Comment: The problem with square function might probably be caused by the absence of non-linearity between layers.

Comment: @viceriel  No, I didn't. But the point (pixels) are evenly distrubuted (not guassian) amongst both axis, y and x. What else di I have to do to normalize it?

Comment: @KrishnaKishoreAndhavarapu How should i delinearize the connections or whatever you mean? Isn't the non linear sigmoidal logistic function enough?

Comment: Ok. You have for example 2 as x and you can from network answer 4 because of y = x^2. You shouldn't use value 2 in training set. You should normalize data between 0-1 interval. Sigmoid function maximum is 1 , so you can't expect 4 as answer.

Comment: Yeah that is true for regression, but i actually made this picture with a classifier network which should classify every pixel as either "under" (0) or "over" (1) the function, which it is doing, but only proorly. I suspect it has something to do with my bias, because the bias would move some neurons away from the point of origin [0, 0] and thus make the "function" more smooth

Comment: You should also scale down the pixel values to range between 0-1

Comment: If you are using sigmoid activation function, it will introduce the required non-linearity